# How to redirect from any activity to next one using click button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm making simple quiz application in android studio, firstly I created one main quiz activity, PagerAdapter class and six fragments. Now I want to add login activity to begining of this pages. When I click the 'Login' button , I want this Login activity redirect to main quiz page. I try that below code but when I executed the code , application still start main quiz page.And I added class name to manifest.xml. What else can I do it?

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final EditText etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    Button btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    Button btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent mainQuizPaqe = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainQuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainQuizPaqe);


        }
    });

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent registerScreen = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(registerScreen);

        }
    });
}}
```

### MainQuizActivity

```
public class MainQuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager pager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_quiz);

    pager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    // Fragment manager to add fragment in viewpager we will pass object of Fragment manager to adpater class.
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();

    //object of PagerAdapter passing fragment manager object as a parameter of constructor of PagerAdapter class.
    PagerAdapter adapter=new PagerAdapter(manager);

    //set Adapter to view pager
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set tablayout with viewpager
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    // adding functionality to tab and viewpager to manage each other when a page is changed or when a tab is selected
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));


}
```

}

Comment: Post your MainQuizActivity code. Probably you are doing something there.

Comment: Did your log generate some errors?

Comment: it has six fragment firstly opened Question1 fragment. And I try to redirect to Question1 class but still not works.

Comment: Please explan better what you want to do with your fragments.

Comment: Each Fragment have text view ,radio buttons , button and controls for one question ,whether if its answer is equal the  right answer.

Comment: I don't wanna know whats inside fragments, just want to know what are you trying to redirect to Question1 class..

Comment: Sorry, ı didnt explain it clearly, but  I solved the problem. It was about manifest.xml. because of Intent filters. 
Thank you so much for your attentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your manifest, I'm guessing that you haven't set the correct intent filter.  Make sure you are setting intent filter to have the `LAUNCHER` flag for the the login activity to be launched:

```
<activity
    android:name="LoginActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If you don't set the intent filter on the activity in the manifest, it won't set it as the first activity.

Comment: This won't save his error. From `LoginActivity` he want's to go on `MainQuizActivity`

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin I guess that BlackHatSamurai is right. The LoginActivity seems to be correct, the problem could be in the Manifest.

Comment: Oh, yes. I'm still in mind with first question. He has edited couple of times.. He's right. My bad..

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BlackHatSamurai.